# How to trigger latest Android Systrace command's markers for jank and frames?

Tags: android, systrace

The latest Android Systrace pages - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html#options-4.3 - show 'Alerts' and 'Frames' trace lines, with circles where bad things happen.

I haven't been able to create a trace.html file with those marks, despite seeing plenty of jank.

Does anyone know what command Google might have used to create the page they screenshotted? They don't provide it, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version described in that doc is only available in Android SDK platform tools 23 rc4 or higher. That's currently only available in tools preview channel in the SDK manager, but will be part of the default tools package once version 23 hits the primary release channel.

Answer (score 0):

No special commands are needed to view the alert circles.
Using the latest version and [starting systrace like you would normally](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html) should suffice.

- Make sure you are not zoomed in a part that does not contain any
  alerts.
- In the left column you should have a label `Alerts`. Make sure you
  did not accidentally scroll down to hide this part. It should be located above `Kernel` which lists your CPU's and below `Interactions`.